# the set of well formed formulas

Tags: logic

Want to prove that W_p is countably infinite

where W_p = { Well formed formulas }

Additional: Well-formed formulas are expressions in predicate logic that capture the idea of making good grammatical sense in any mathematical context

Also, we know that if a set maps onto the positive Natural Numbers, the set is countable or countably infinite

I need help showing how this mapping works
Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this question properly unless you post full details of what a well-formed formula means in your course/textbook/whatever.

Comment: The usual specification for *first-order* language include : sentential conncetives, quantifiers, a countable infinite set of (individual) *variables*, a set (possibly empty) of (individual) constants and a set (possibly empty) of predicate symbols. A *wff* is a *finite* string of symbols; thus having countable infinite many symbols, the set of finite strings is countable.

Comment: This is only true if the language is (at most) countable.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

1. Suppose $S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots$ is a countably infinite family of sets, each of which is finite or countable.  Then the union of the $S_i$ is finite or countable.
2. Let $S_i$ be the set of well-formed formulas containing exactly $i$ symbols. Then each $S_i$ is at most countable.